# ClassCastException during instantiation of ClientBuilder in wildfly

Tags: java, spring, maven, war, resteasy

I have a web app which is being deployed to wildfly 8.1.0 Final.  It uses Spring, RESTEasy, etc. In one place in the code, a `ClientBuilder` is needed to create a `javax.ws.rs.client.Client`:

```
   public class CustomClientImpl implements CustomClient {
      // [...]
      private Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
      // [...]
   }
```

This is generating the following nested exception (skipped first 5).  In short, the error is a failed cast from

> jar:file:/c:/Programs/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/javax/ws/rs/api/main/jaxrs-api-3.0.8.Final.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class
>
> to
>
> vfs:/c:/Programs/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/bin/content/ybsearch.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-api-3.0.8.Final.jar/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class

which seem as if they ought to be compatible given that it is the same class in identical jar files. [??]

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.lilblackbook.search.api.response.ListingProcessorImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar:file:/c:/Programs/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/javax/ws/rs/api/main/jaxrs-api-3.0.8.Final.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class to vfs:/c:/Programs/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/bin/content/ybsearch.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-api-3.0.8.Final.jar/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:267)
        ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar:file:/c:/Programs/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/javax/ws/rs/api/main/jaxrs-api-3.0.8.Final.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class to vfs:/c:/Programs/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/bin/content/ybsearch.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-api-3.0.8.Final.jar/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class
        at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:97)
        at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient(ClientBuilder.java:114)
        at com.lilblackbook.search.api.skynet.CustomClientImpl.<init>(CustomClientImpl.java:56)
        at com.lilblackbook.search.api.response.ListingProcessorImpl.<init>(ListingProcessorImpl.java:38)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
```

My pom includes the dependency for

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
     <!--scope>provided</scope-->
  </dependency>
```

Given that `jaxrs-api-3.0.8.Final.jar` is provided by wildfly, I tried `provided` as dependency scope but that generates a `ClassNotFoundException`.  When I include it, the `ClassCastException` detailed above is generated.

Is that enough information? Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Brother, did you ever find an answer to this :) (/me stuck on the same issue)

Comment: share the answers if anyone finds for this issue

Answer (score 1):

To solve this error, I had to change the implementation I used for JaxRS Client.

I went from Jersey:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

to Smallrye:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
   <artifactId>smallrye-rest-client</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```